# How do I save a web page, programmatically?

Tags: caching, web-applications, screen-scraping, html-content-extraction

I would like to save a web page programmatically.

I don't mean merely save the HTML. I would also like automatically to store all associated files (images, CSS files, maybe embedded SWF, etc), and hopefully rewrite the links for local browsing.

The intended usage is a personal bookmarks application, in which link content is cached in case the original copy is taken down.

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/), specifically the -p flag

```
−p  −−page−requisites
This option causes Wget to download all the ﬁles
that are necessary to properly display
a givenHTML  page. Thisincludes such
things as inlined images, sounds, and
referenced stylesheets.
```

The following command:

```
wget -p http://<site>/1.html
```

Will download page.html and all files it requires.

Comment: And why did someone downvote me? I mean the -1 doesn't bother me so much as I'd like to correct any issues there might be with my answer...

Comment: This looks pretty good, except sometimes the output doesn't look the same as the page that I copied. For example, I tried to 'wget -p' http://ffffound.com/image/3d3795b5447291980a40f3719dea4b5b15ff3ec9
However, the related images which are laid out as a horizontal list, now become a long vertical list, one-per-line. Why?

Answer (score 2):

On Windows: you can run IE as a com object and pull everything out.

On other thing, you can take the source of Mozilla.

In Java, [Lobo](http://lobobrowser.org/java-browser.jsp).

Or commons-httpclient and write a lot of code.

Comment: +1 if you need stuff like background images referenced in stylesheets and CSS imports, you need a real-world HTML and CSS parser. That's half a browser there already, so you might as well just do it with a real browser. Easiest to embed IE, or work as a Firefox extension.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the MHTML format (which is what IE uses). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MHTML

In other words, you'd be downloading each object (image, css, etc.) to your computer, and then "embedding" them, via Base64, into a single file.

Comment: What programming language do you want to use?

Comment: Here's one that uses VB: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/aspnethtml2mht.aspx