# How to fire "save website" event programatically

Tags: javascript, browser

As I stumbled across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732318/how-do-i-save-a-web-page-programmatically) on how to save a web-site, I wondered if there is any way to fire the typical `CTRL`+`S` "save" event to save only the current web-page programatically. Is there any way to fire this event from the browser directly (with e. g. a button-click)? Or is this limited as a user-only action and restricted by the browser? I'd assume that action like these are restricted due to safety reasons - if that is the case, are there any workarounds? Common ways to achieve such things? This would probably include things like pressing e. g. `F11` for fullscreen.

Comment: Saving a web-page is not the same thing as saving a website.

Comment: Browser extensions can save web-pages, last time I checked.

Comment: @Dai Indeed - English isn't my first language so I wasn't that toughtful about choosing the right term. but your right- web-pages is what I meant. Browser-Extension may do the trick, but I'm more curios if theres a way to fire it from the page directly (by e. g. a button click). :)

Comment: There is no DOM/JS API for invoking the browser's save-current-web-page dialog - but  if the user has an extension installed then in-page scripts could try communicating with the extension - or JS could try saving the page themselves by reconstituting the HTML from the current DOM, persisting that as a string value in a `Blob` passed to `URL.createObjectURL` and then open a download-prompt using `createElement('a')./* etc */click()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- There is no DOM/JS API for invoking the browser's save-current-web-page dialog.
- ...but there *is* [a Chrome Extension API for saving web-pages](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/pageCapture/).
- ...but if the user has an extension installed then the extension's scripts - or even *extension-aware* in-page scripts could try communicating with the extension to instruct it to trigger the save-page-dialog.
- ...or JS could try saving the page themselves by reconstituting the HTML from the current DOM, persisting that as a string value in a Blob passed to URL.createObjectURL and then open a download-prompt, like so:

```
function promptToSaveCurrentReconstitutedWebPage() {

    const htmlEl  = document.documentElement; // i.e. the root <html> element.
    const html    = htmlEl.outerHTML; // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML
    
    const blob    = new Blob( [ html ], { type: "text/html" } );
    const blobUri = URL.createObjectURL( blob );
    
    const a       = document.createElement( 'a' );

    a.href      = blobUri;
    a.download  = 'ThisPage.html';
    a.className = 'i-have-no-life';

    document.body.appendChild( a );
    a.click();

    // objectURIs are expensive: need to clean them up.
    function cleanUpObjectUris() {
        const ahrefs = Array.from( document.querySelectorAll( 'a.i-have-no-life[href][download]' ) );
        for( const a in ahrefs ) {
            URL.revokeObjectURL( a.href );
            a.remove();
        }
    }
    window.setTimeout( cleanUpObjectUris, 30000 );
}
```

- Note this won't include any images, stylesheets, or other external resources.

  - Implementing that is an exercise left for the reader.

    - Hint: you **do not** need to use `data:` URIs or any Base64.

---

Unfortunately I can't demonstrate this using a StackOverflow snippet because of the extra security/sandboxing applied (i.e. the snippet below won't work: the `blobUri` will be of the form `blob:null/{guid}` [which means it's a sandboxed blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28377733/url-createobjecturl-returns-a-blob-with-null-prepended-eg-blobnull-12415-63), but this should work on the wider-web, including as a bookmarklet.

```js
function promptToSaveCurrentReconstitutedWebPage() {

    const htmlEl  = document.documentElement; // i.e. the root <html> element.
    const html    = htmlEl.outerHTML; // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML
    
    const blob    = new Blob( [ html ], { type: "text/html" } );
    const blobUri = URL.createObjectURL( blob );
    
    const a       = document.createElement( 'a' );
    a.href     = blobUri;
    a.download = 'ThisPage.html';

    document.body.appendChild( a );
    a.click();
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="promptToSaveCurrentReconstitutedWebPage()">Click here to save this web-page</button>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent consequat nunc risus, eu euismod ligula sagittis id. Nullam pretium congue dolor ac volutpat. Pellentesque imperdiet mi dapibus purus pharetra, quis egestas felis tempus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Nunc ac efficitur lectus. Cras sed magna quam. Etiam finibus urna nec urna accumsan imperdiet. Proin dignissim, velit sit amet ornare vehicula, ipsum nibh pulvinar tellus, nec dignissim erat odio id neque. In massa neque, porta eu diam ac, hendrerit condimentum dui. Sed cursus mattis auctor. Morbi id ligula sit amet dui molestie interdum. Quisque sit amet libero sodales, molestie felis ac, tincidunt lectus.</p>

<p>Pellentesque condimentum sem velit, in tincidunt quam mattis vel. Nulla sagittis nisl nec erat tristique sodales. Quisque in neque mollis, varius sapien sed, interdum felis. Aenean at fermentum turpis, ut elementum enim. Vestibulum egestas faucibus consequat. Donec lacinia ex quis quam lacinia vehicula. Vestibulum posuere tortor quis finibus viverra. Vestibulum congue sagittis lorem, eget laoreet diam egestas et.</p>

<p>Integer sit amet odio ligula. Nulla congue viverra ultricies. Donec maximus enim ornare, molestie orci non, gravida ex. Nullam semper vestibulum nulla, quis laoreet felis ornare sed. Praesent aliquet libero vitae velit elementum, vitae pulvinar leo pulvinar. Donec consequat neque ut ipsum ornare ullamcorper. Cras sit amet porta augue. Vestibulum nibh velit, laoreet quis sagittis euismod, consectetur a arcu. Curabitur pharetra, odio in consequat accumsan, purus velit tristique justo, in hendrerit purus ligula vitae magna. Vestibulum vitae scelerisque ligula. Morbi aliquam molestie ex sit amet tincidunt. Pellentesque magna est, tincidunt in est sed, facilisis egestas nibh. Donec malesuada, metus vitae finibus feugiat, leo massa cursus erat, vitae tempor augue sapien vel augue. Praesent vitae urna nulla.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce fringilla quam at ex molestie aliquet. Duis ornare neque ac dolor convallis eleifend. Duis ullamcorper est in nunc consequat, vitae elementum massa lacinia. Mauris mollis massa eget mauris molestie egestas vitae sed nisi. Praesent sit amet eros sollicitudin purus imperdiet congue eget vehicula enim. Fusce lacinia, elit ut vulputate feugiat, dui mauris imperdiet dui, quis sagittis turpis lacus vel lorem. Nam malesuada ultricies massa consequat fringilla. Donec in elit ac arcu placerat aliquet eu eu felis. Nullam dictum dui quis velit accumsan ornare.</p>

<p>Fusce hendrerit pretium lectus, eu vehicula est tristique sit amet. Aenean nec magna id velit pellentesque accumsan. Pellentesque eget maximus tellus, id bibendum lectus. Phasellus vitae elementum velit, vitae finibus nisi. Maecenas faucibus efficitur felis. Curabitur viverra tortor urna, efficitur volutpat tellus fermentum sit amet. Morbi non cursus mauris. Suspendisse porta libero sit amet est tincidunt iaculis. Aliquam et ullamcorper ipsum. Donec sit amet gravida ligula. Nam nec lobortis mi. Integer imperdiet nunc ut gravida malesuada. Praesent porta sem in erat vestibulum, ac commodo erat vulputate. Nunc cursus mauris eu nisl scelerisque, eget rhoncus arcu vehicula.</p>
```

Comment: That's cool! Didn't think of that!